# Getting error type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' after flutter upgrade

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I'm making an app which stores data in json. Here's the code for it and then displaying it listview:-

```
class CardData extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CardDataState createState() => _CardDataState();
}

class _CardDataState extends State<CardData> {
  TextEditingController title = new TextEditingController();

  File jsonFile;
  Directory dir;
  String fileName = 'myFile.json';
  bool fileExists = false;
  List fileContent;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getApplicationDocumentsDirectory().then((Directory directory) {
      dir = directory;
      jsonFile = new File(dir.path + '/' + fileName);
      fileExists = jsonFile.existsSync();
      if (fileExists)
        this.setState(
            () => fileContent = json.decode(jsonFile.readAsStringSync()));
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    title.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void createFile(
      Map<String, dynamic> content, Directory dir, String fileName) {
    print("Creating file!");
    File file = new File(dir.path + "/" + fileName);
    file.createSync();
    fileExists = true;
    file.writeAsStringSync(json.encode(content));
  }

  void writeToFile(String title, dynamic date) {
    print("Writing to file!");
    Map<String, dynamic> content = {'title': title, 'date': date};
    if (fileExists) {
      print("File exists");
      List jsonFileContent = json.decode(jsonFile.readAsStringSync());
      jsonFileContent.add(content);
      jsonFile.writeAsStringSync(json.encode(jsonFileContent));
    } else {
      print("File does not exist!");
      createFile(content, dir, fileName);
    }
    this.setState(() => fileContent = json.decode(jsonFile.readAsStringSync()));
    print(fileContent);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0)),
          new Text(
            "File content: ",
            style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          new Text(fileContent.toString()),
          new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0)),
          new Text("Add to JSON file: "),
          new TextField(
            controller: title,
            decoration: textInputDecoration.copyWith(
                hintText: 'title',
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.info, color: Colors.white)),
          ),
          new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0)),
          new RaisedButton(
            child: new Text("save new document"),
            onPressed: () => writeToFile(title.text, 'ok'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It was working fine till yesterday but now, after running `flutter upgrade` I'm getting this problem:-

`_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>` and here's my `flutter doctor` output:-

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 1.22.0-10.0.pre.317, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.900], locale en-IN)
 
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 3.4)
[√] VS Code (version 1.49.0)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
```

I've tried uninstalling,run in flutter clean, looked up other question but haven't gotten any answers, How can I solve this?

Comment: Which line are you getting the error?

Comment: You should switch to stable channel

Comment: 23rd line I'm getting error.

Comment: It looks like you're taking the output of json.decode, Map<String, dynamic>, and trying to assign it to a List.  Making fileContent a Map<String, dynamic> should work.

Comment: Yes but It will not have a list of maps, only a single map.

Comment: I want a list of maps, it was working with this code now all of a sudden, I'm getting this error.